# inline-flex ignores parent's padding when inline-block doesn't

Tags: css, flexbox

I am making a grid using css flexbox. The issue I am facing is that when I changed grid's display from inline-block to inline-flex the children no longer respect padding-right. Isn't inline-flex supposed to behave the same as inline-block in this respect, and if so what explains this difference? The reason I want to switch to inline-flex is because I want children (whose display is set to inline-block) to line up vertically. I am also curious as to why overflow-y impacts behavior.

```css
         body { margin: 0; }

         /* wrapper sets the overall height. We use flex to make contents fill height. */
         .wrapper {
             height: 300px;
             display: flex;
             flex-direction: column;
         }

         /* grid can have header and body. header is omitted for now. */
         .grid {
             flex: 1 1 0; /* this makes grid same height as wrapper */
             display: inline-flex;
             flex-direction: column; /* lays out contents vertically */
             overflow-y: auto;   /* overflow-y strangely impacts whether padding is honored */
             padding-left: 15px;
             padding-right: 15px;
         }

         .grid-body {
             margin-top: 50px;
             margin-bottom: 50px;
             display: inline-block; /* makes width the same as row */
         }

         .row {
           width: 1420px;
           height: 30px;
         }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-body">
          <div class="row" style="background-color:#de7;"></div>
          <div class="row" style="background-color:#7ed;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: both behave the same from the outside, but inside they are completely different. One is creating a flexbox container and the other a simple block container.This is a major difference

Comment: Update: in Edge and Firefox the right padding is ignored regardless of inline-block or inline-flex. Only Chrome shows a difference.